# How to use 'sed' to print lines with '1' ONLY

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file which has information regarding all 23 pairs of chromosomes (CHROM).  I want all the information regarding only chromosome 1 written to an output file. Therefore the first character of the line has to '1' only.

How can I use sed or (awk?) to best do this?

I tried this below but got line numbers added as well as other misc...

```
sed -e = '/^1/' input.vcf > output_CHROM1.vcf
```

Example file:

```
##INFO=<ID=AA,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Ancestral Allele">
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO
1   69224   COSM3677745 A   C   .   .   COSMIC_71;TSA=SNV
2   69230   COSM3677746 A   C   .   .   COSMIC_71;TSA=SNV
23  69230   COSM3677746 A   C   .   .   COSMIC_71;TSA=SNV
```

Comment: Why not `grep`? E.g. `grep '^1\b' input.vcf`.

Comment: Yes this works but does not save to file..

Comment: So add `> output_CHROM1.vcf` to it...?

Comment: if you want the points add your answer... I will sign off. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-n` to not print the input and add `p` to the pattern to print the lines that match:

```
sed -n '/^1\b/p' input.vcf > output_CHROM1.vcf
```

Answer (score 5):

An easy, and quite typical, task for `grep`:

```
grep '^1\b' input.vcf > output_CHROM1.vcf
```

Comment: Yup, jobs like this are why grep was invented.